# How can I calculate $AB$ in a quadrilateral figure $(ABCD)$

Tags: geometry

$AD=3cm$, $DC=4cm$, $BC=5cm$. The diagonals of this quad figure must also be perpendicular. Find $AB$.

Comment: Why did you tag it by [tag:general-relativity]?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Let the intersection of two diagonals be $P$. Then we have:
$$\begin{multline}AD^2+BC^2=(AP^2+DP^2)+(BP^2+CP^2)\\=(AP^2+BP^2)+(CP^2+DP^2)=AB^2+CD^2,\end{multline}$$
since the diagonals are perpendicular.

Answer (score 2):

Let $O$ be the intersecting point between the two diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.

Then by Pythagoras' Theorem we have the following identities:

$$\begin{cases}
AO^2 + DO^2 = AD^2 = 9 & (1)\\
DO^2 + CO^2 = CD^2 = 16 & (2)\\
CO^2 + BO^2 = BC^2 = 25 & (3)\\
BO^2 + AO^2 = AB^2 & (4)
 \end{cases}$$

Note that $(1) + (3) - (2) = (4)$ thus $AB^2 = 9+25-16 = 18\Rightarrow AB = 3\sqrt{2}$